# calling new fragment error with no view found by id

Tags: java, android

im calling this code 
`getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.menu_frame_two, new SlideRight())
            .commit();`

causing

```
10-14 07:12:57.895: E/AndroidRuntime(2293): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f07010e (com.test:id/menu_frame_two) for fragment SlideRight{a7754e48 #0 id=0x7f07010e}.
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that there's no `menu_frame_two` view in your current layout. Double check you don't have any typo.

Comment: but when i put this code to another layout is work fine. how come

Comment: Well, maybe in 'another layout' there's a view with id `menu_frame_two`. Just look into the xml which layout is failing, chances are there's no such `id`.

Comment: i'm using another layout to call a fragment in order to refresh the data in the layout.

Comment: Could you please post the xml layout you're talking about?

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this
    SlideRight fragment;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.yourxml);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // Add the fragment on initial activity setup
            fragment = new SlideRight();
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.menu_frame_two, fragment).commit();
        } else {
            // Or set the fragment from restored state info
            fragment = (SlideRight) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(android.R.id.menu_frame_two);
        }
    }
```

Comment: this don;t work for me. My case is another layout calling a new fragment in order to refresh the data.

Comment: for example : i' m having 2 class 1 is SlideRight extend ListFragment and 1 is SlideRight2 extend FragmentActivity. My SlideRight2 calling SlideRight in order to refresh the data in SlideRight. Any example how to call a new fragment to refresh the data?